# Is there a way to loop through a list in Python and check if a certain string is in every string element within the list?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to loop through a list and check each element of the list for a specific string pattern (some sort of nucleotide pattern for example and assuming all elements within the list are strings). How would one do this? I've attempted using the all() function in an if statement that was embedded in a for loop, but that didn't seem to work. Example of what I mean below:

```
 for i in range(0, len(list)):
    if thing in all(list):
        add thing to another list
```

Comment: So you want to ask "is this substring present in every string in this list?"

Comment: @John Gordon Yes exactly! My apologies if my question was not clear, I can edit it.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a list comprehension to check each list element.  Then sum that resulting list and assert that every string matched.

```py
def allList(lst, elem):
    return len(lst) == sum([elem in x for x in lst])

inp = ["ATCGCGTTA", "CGCGATTA", "TTAGCGCA"]
print(allList(inp, "TTA"))  # True
```

Comment: While this works, it's pretty bad. Better indeed use `all` (and a generator expression).